# What all Mobile Permission we can ask in a PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I want to know all the permission list that a PWA can acquire in Android Mobile & iOS Mobile.

Following permission I know:
1. Camera
2. Push Notification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Permission Registry:**

```
'accelerometer', 
'accessibility-events', 
'ambient-light-sensor', 
'background-sync', 
'camera'​, 
'clipboard-read', 
'clipboard-write', 
'geolocation', 
'gyroscope', 
'magnetometer', 
'microphone', 
'midi',     
'notifications', 
'payment-handler', 
'persistent-storage'
'push'
```

And you can query them with the [permission.query() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query) to get the state of a user permission:

```
navigator.permissions.query(PermissionDescriptor)
    .then(
          function(permissionStatus) { ... }
         )
```